# How to click an image and reload the current page in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm still a newbie in Reactjs and I'm trying to build a single page for my project. And I'm thinking to click the logo image and reload the page.

I have tried 2 ways, one is using `<a href="javscript:location:reload: true">` in front of image element but I got this `Script URL is a form of eval  no-script-url` in my console.

I also tried `onClick` eventlistener but nothing is working.
I appreciate any helps, or new way to build this?

Below is my Home.js

```
class Home extends React.Component {
   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <a href="javascript:location.reload(true)"><img src={MindScribeLogo} className="HomePage" alt="logo" /></a>
       <div>
         <img src={MindScribeZebra} className="HomePage" alt="zebra" />
       </div>
     </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;
```

Below is my App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <Home/>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm you can try a basic onClick function. hrefs are not supposed to contain scripts.

```
<img onClick={() => this.reloadPage()}/>

reloadPage () {
  window.location.reload()
}
```

Comment: But why would you say href is not supposed to contain scripts?

Comment: i'm quite noob, but this thread seems to explain the 'eval' warning better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea